# How to inspect the form values in hook_user_update()?

Tags: users, 10

In Drupal 7, one could have the following `hook_user_update()` to
return TRUE if the 'roles' has been edited:

```
function example_user_update(&$edit, $account, $category) {
  isset($edit['roles']) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

In Drupal 10, the signature of the hook has changed, and we no longer
have direct access to the paramter `$edit` (the array of form values
submitted by the user).  How do one do this in Drupal 9/10?

```
function example_user_update(EntityInterface $account) {
  // What is the equivalent?
}
```

Comment: The equivalent now would probably be to check `$account->roles` against `$account->original->roles`

Comment: @Clive Thanks. I guess that will be a workaround, if there is no way to inspect the actual form.

Comment: It's not really a workaround so much as making better use of an improved architecture - update hooks aren't necessarily triggered by a form submission, so always having form data available doesn't make sense. If the update was triggered by a REST call should your logic not also be considered? (rhetorical question, but that's the thinking behind it). If you need to do something with the form data, you can always hook into the form itself

Comment: @Clive Thanks for explanation. That makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code:

```
function drupal_practice_user_update($account) {
 $roles = $account->original->getRoles();
    if ($roles !== $account->getRoles()) {
      \Drupal::messenger()->addMessage(t('Role has 
       updated'));
    }
    else{
       \Drupal::messenger()->addWarning(t('Role has not 
        updated'));   
    }
}
```

As you can see `$account` parameter holds the value of the fields in a users profile.